# django double filter with the same field

Tags: python, django

How to double filter with the same field? this is my sample below, i didnt get any data , i just want to filter the **Status = 'cut off completed'** and **Status = 'cut off completed'** but i didnt get any data from it.

```
deliverySchedule = DeliverySchedule.objects.filter(Status = 'cut off completed').filter(Status = 'Active').order_by('deliverySchedule')
```

my data from django admin

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use double filter? One filter is capable enough to fetch all the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You here filter for `Schedule` objects where the status is *both* `cut off completed` and `Active`. But the value in a field can not be two different things.

You can make use of [**`Q`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) to specify a logical or:

```
from django.db.models import Q

deliverySchedule = DeliverySchedule.objects.filter(
    Q(Status='cut off completed') |
    Q(Status='Active')
).order_by('deliverySchedule')
```

but likely it is more elegant to usee a [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
deliverySchedule = DeliverySchedule.objects.filter(
    Status__in=['cut off completed', 'Active']
).order_by('deliverySchedule')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Q
deliverySchedule = DeliverySchedule.objects.filter(Q(Status = 'cut off completed') | Q(Status = 'Active')).order_by('deliverySchedule')
```

Based on your explanation I think using this above query will serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) like so:

```
deliverySchedule = DeliverySchedule.objects.filter(Status__in=['cut off completed', 'Active']).order_by('deliverySchedule')
```

If your queryset is empty then there might not be any `DeliverySchedule` entries with that status.